# Sum daily values for every month in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have got a matrix with values in.

The first column of the matrix is the date in the following form, `19260701` pr `YYYYMMDD`.

The other columns of the matrix are series.

```
19260702    0.026   0.000   NaN 1.175
19260706    0.009   0.000   NaN 1.842
19260707    1.388   0.001   NaN 9.061
19260708    1.147   0.028   NaN 0.067
19260709    0.604   0.018   NaN 0.000
19260710    7.255   0.020   NaN 0.005
19260712    0.085   0.093   NaN 1.832
19260713    0.163   0.025   NaN 3.897
19260714    1.294   0.545   NaN 0.188
19260715    0.256   0.077   NaN 0.001
19260716    0.001   0.002   NaN 0.018
19260717    0.000   0.015   NaN 1.863
19260719    0.002   0.062   NaN 1.465
19260720    2.761   0.028   NaN 6.453
19260721    1.998   0.067   NaN 0.328
19260722    0.160   0.123   NaN 0.651
19260723    0.009   0.000   NaN 0.001
19260724    0.005   0.000   NaN 0.000
19260726    0.016   0.002   NaN 0.860
19260727    0.022   0.000   NaN 0.329
19260728    0.002   0.001   NaN 0.857
19260729    0.000   0.343   NaN 2.125
19260730    0.002   0.001   NaN 1.265
19260731    0.000   0.000   NaN 0.283
19260802    0.000   0.010   NaN 0.815
19260803    0.000   1.020   NaN 27.701
19260804    0.000   0.197   NaN 4.162
19260805    0.027   0.016   NaN 42.120
19260806    0.046   0.200   NaN 15.163
19260807    0.284   0.004   NaN 0.382
19260809    1.330   0.000   NaN 3.102
19260810    1.066   0.016   NaN 0.035
19260811    0.261   0.119   NaN 0.249
19260812    0.014   0.031   NaN 328.139
19260813    0.024   0.042   NaN 40.248
19260814    0.094   0.047   NaN 1.460
19260816    0.042   0.007   NaN 25.928
```

Is it possible to Sum the values in each column of the matrix based on the month?

Apologise,

Following the comments,

I dont just want to sum by month, but each yearmonth, i.e sum Jan 1960, Feb 1960 etc.

Comment: Does _the same month_ mean _the same month and year_, or _the same month regardless of year_?

Comment: i want to sum for each month each year, so 199607 is a month I want to sum, I dont just want ot sum every 07

Comment: Do this: `t = datetime(num2str(data(:,1)),'InputFormat','yyyyMMdd');`
`[y,m]= ymd(t);` and then you can use `[y,m]` instead of `month` and `unique` with the `rows` flag in Luis' answer

Comment: t = datetime(num2str(data(:,1)),'InputFormat','yyyyMMdd'); 
[y,m]= ymd(t);

[y,m] = mod(floor(data2(:,1)/100-1), 100)+1;
[~, ~, month_id] = rows([y,m]);
result = splitapply(@sum, data2(:,2:end), month_id)

Comment: @SardarUsama please be patient with me, but this doesn't work what am I doing wrong

Comment: `rows` is not a function. You are supposed to use `unique` with the `rows` flag. `[~, ~, month_id] = unique([y,m],'rows');` and you do not need the line with `mod` and `floor` functions

Comment: LuisMendo has  edited his answer to include a better approach.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`unique`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) to get a label for each month, and then [`splitapply`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/splitapply.html) to accumulate values in the other columns based on month label ([`accumarray`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) would work but only on one column).

If you consider April 2018 and April 2019 the **same month**:

```
month = mod(floor(data(:,1)/100-1), 100)+1;
[month_name, ~, month_id] = unique(month);
result = splitapply(@sum, data(:,2:end), month_id);
result_with_month = [month_name result];
```

If you consider  April 2018 and April 2019 **different months**:

```
month = floor(data(:,1)/100);
[month_name, ~, month_id] = unique(month);
result = splitapply(@sum, data(:,2:end), month_id);
result_with_month = [month_name result];
```

Example results with the provided data:

```
result =
   1.0e+02 *
   0.172050000000000   0.014510000000000   NaN   0.345660000000000
   0.031880000000000   0.017090000000000   NaN   4.895040000000000
result_with_month =
   1.0e+05 *
   1.926070000000000   0.000172050000000   0.000014510000000   NaN   0.000345660000000
   1.926080000000000   0.000031880000000   0.000017090000000   NaN   0.004895040000000
```

Comment: Why not simply use `month = ceil(data(:, 1) / 100)`, when the "information" stored in `month` is neglected after applying `unique`? :-)

Comment: @HansHirse I'm using `mod` to gather the same month across years. I'll clarify

Answer (score 5):

This is a typical example where you can use table instead of matrix.

```
A = [19260702    0.026   0.000   NaN 1.175
     ...
     19260816    0.042   0.007   NaN 25.928];

% Matrix to table conversion
T = array2table(A,'VariableNames',{'DATE','S1','S2','S3','S4'});
% We add a new column "month"
T.MONTH = floor(T.DATE/100);
% varfun can apply a custom function to your table and group the result according 
% to one (or more) variable(s)
Result = varfun(@sum,T,'InputVariables',{'S1','S2','S3','S4'},'GroupingVariables','MONTH')
```

[image]

**Lazy guy option:**

If you're lazy and don't want to add manualy the variable's name you can also use linear indexing:

```
T = array2table(A) %column name will be 'A1','A2',....
T.MONTH = floor(T{:,1}/100);
Result = varfun(@sum,T,'InputVariables',2:5,'GroupingVariables','MONTH')
```

**Code golf option**

If you like short code the arguments name can be shortened. For example if `InputVariables` is the only argument name starting with `I` you can simply use `I` instead of `InputVariables`.

```
Result = varfun(@sum,T,'I',2:5,'G',6)
```

Comment: The method by @LuisMendo seems to work perfectly. What would be the benefits if any of your method. Thanks very much for your answer!

Comment: It's a matter of personal preference. Both methods work. For example a Python user will probably find this approach more familiar if he already used a Dataframe. It's also possible to apply several function at once with: `varfun(@(x) [sum(x),mean(x)],...`

Answer (score -1):

Yes. You could for example use [accumarray](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) here.

With it, it is possible to identify if a value belongs to a certain month and "tag" it using [histc](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histc.html) function. Values with similar "tags" are summed by the accumarray function.

Comment: I appreciate your answer, I have heard of accumarray but I am still having troubles with actually summing them with the date in the current format etc.

Comment: This should've been posted as a comment. This is not a complete answer

Comment: @user30609 I don't quite understand your problem then. Do you just need a sample code of how to sum values inside a matrix?

Comment: @SardarUsama What do you think I should add in order to make this a complete answer?

Comment: @user22485: This is not a link-only answer. Links to the documentation are just a convenience. The function names are right there in the answer, typing `doc <functionname>` in MATLAB gets you to exactly the same page. It’s not a complete answer, but it’s a valid answer.

Comment: @user22485 downvoting is fine if you dislike it but it's not link-only. [Here's some help](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288056/5067311) to get you started with not-an-answers. And [another explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer).